# Nginx listen two different ports on the two network cards

Tags: nginx

How to make a HTTP server listen two different ports on the two network cards with nginx?

Ex:

A HTTP server listens two network address, 192.168.1.20:8888 and 192.168.2.20:8889

I've already known that writing the two servers listening a port with one network address is workable but it is too lengthy for me...

```
server {
   listen       8888;
   server_name  192.168.1.20;
       ...
 }

server {
   listen       8889;
   server_name  192.168.2.20;
       ...
 }
```

Does anyone know how to do it with much more structured way?

Comment: Have you tried `server { listen 192.168.1.20:8888; listen 192.168.2.20:8889; ...`?